# Visual Studio seems to compile headers as .c files

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, header-files

When I try to build a C project that contains .c and .h files, Visual Studio gives me weird errors, like this is the code for my header (which should be perfectly fine):

```
#ifndef _CLIENT_SOCKET_H_
#define _CLIENT_SOCKET_H_

#include "common.h"
#include "buffer.h"

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef void* wsocket;

int socket_create(wsocket* sock, int port, const char* addr, struct sockaddr_in *s_addr); //This is line 28

int socket_connect(wsocket sock, struct sockaddr_in s_addr);

bool socket_recv_buffer(wsocket, buffer_t*);

bool socket_send_buffer(wsocket, buffer_t);

int socket_destroy(wsocket* sock);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* _CLIENT_SOCKET_H_ */
```

And I get errors like:

```
syntax error: missing '{' before '.'
```

or

```
syntax error: '.'
```

both at line 28.

It seems like it's trying to compile the header as if it was a .c file, since it wants a body for the function and such. Do you have any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Cut and paste the error message

Comment: `.c` files and `.h` files are the same language; functions can either be defined or declared (with or without bodies) in both.  You have an actual syntax error.

Comment: What's all these the syntax error then? I posted code for my header.

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in another included (or including) file.

Comment: header files are pretty much copy/pasted into files that include them.  They're not really treated specially.  Perhaps a missing `;` or `}` in buffer.h?  Difficult to tell with what we've been given to work with.  With, what was it, 400+ errors/warnings in the screenshot you originally posted, seems you've got a lot of places to check for the culprit.

Comment: Try making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah, debugging code for a job is always full of wonders.

Comment: @MadsMarquart It's not always that simple. Sometimes you have small and tidy examples, sometimes it's a huge situation that gives you the error. Going to investigate a bit more and try to post more detail.

Comment: Edit post to indicate line 28  or is that in `"common.h"
 "buffer.h"`

Comment: It's line 28 in the file I've posted, which is called `client_socket.h` Edited btw

Comment: The code you've posted is 27 lines long.  There isn't anything wrong with the code you've posted so far.

Comment: A function declaration that's not a definition is perfectly valid either in a `.h` file or in ` .c` file.

Comment: @Stewart I'm sorry, it's not line 28 here cause I excluded the license commented lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If line 28 in indeed the one you commented, the compilation error is quite surprising: there is no `.` on this line.

A possible explanation is at least one of the identifiers on this line was defined in `common.h` or `buffer.h` as a macro and expanded into a structure member access.

For example:

```
#define socket_create    socket.create
```

Check the contents of these header files.

**EDIT:** the problem was indeed a spurious macro definition in a system header file:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556972(v=vs.85).aspx

`s_addr` is defined in as `#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr`

Using `s_addr` as the name of an argument (or a local variable) leads to a cryptic error message from the compiler, because of the macro expansion...

Comment: I actually just fixed it, the problem had (as usual) nothing to do with the error message: it seemed s_addr was a keyword and I couldn't call my variable like that. Should I make an answer and accept it?

Comment: `s_addr` is not a keyword... is it defined as a macro in your header files or one of Visual Studio's

Comment: I updated the answer with the explanation. `s_addr` indeed cannot be used as an argument name, and the error message is cryptic.

Comment: not a keyword, I meant an already defined word, that's why the compiler didn't accept it as a variable name.

Comment: Yes, and I was on the right track. Note however that `s_addr` could have been defined as a global variable or a function without any such consequences. The problem comes from the definition as a preprocessor macro, a pretty bad idea IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I ran in this issue today as well. And for me the issue was that the item type of the file was set to a source file. I managed to resolve it by going to the properties of the file and setting the item type to C/C++